# "Operation could destabilize the runtime" when trying to upgrade from MVC3 to MVC4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, exception, asp.net-mvc-4

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

What's a good one to troubleshoot this?  I let debug step through everything in global.asax and no errors there.

```
Operation could destabilize the runtime.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   System.Web.Mvc.Razor.MvcWebPageRazorHost.GetRidOfNamespace(String ns) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Razor.MvcWebPageRazorHost..ctor(String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +199
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory.CreateHost(String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +113
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfigCore(RazorWebSectionGroup config, String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +422
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +228
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath) +38
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.CreateHost() +51
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_Host() +56
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode() +92
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() +54
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) +59
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +209
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +15
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +9929933
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +299
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +165
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +33
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath) +40
```

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment as I'm not sure this is exactly your issue. There is a bug in the .NET 4.5 runtime with reflection that caused this error message to rise to the surface for me when using Fluent Validation. See http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/workitem/7096. This matches the exception exactly, so this would probably be a reflection based issue for you. They have a workaround from Microsoft listed in the notes over at the Fluent Validation site. I'd say take a loot at this and track down if you have a reflection based issue.

Comment: UPDATE:  This is a .NET 4.0 project, not .NET 4.5

Comment: @Shane as you can find in the last link in my answer: even pure .NET4 projects use .NET 4.5 runtime if it is installed and thus are subject to the the bug therein!

Comment: I can create a new MVC4 project on the same machine and run it just fine.  I went through and compared all of the assembly references and the web.config and everything seems in order.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem though my project is .Net 4.5. I solved it by following step 7 of [Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806)

It is copied to here as following:

7.If the project references any third-party libraries that are compiled using previous versions of ASP.NET MVC, open the root Web.config file and add the following three bindingRedirect elements under the configuration section:

```
 <configuration>
  <!--... elements deleted for clarity ...-->

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" 
             publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" 
             publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" 
             publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

That is a very strange thing - and the information provided is not enough for reproducing it... so just some things that might lead to what you see:

- Intellitrace (turn it off and see whether it helps)
- any "older controls" used (esp. V 1.1), comment them out and see whether it helps
- Trustlevel, change to `[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]` in AssemblyInfo.cs and see whether it helps

**it might also be a [bug in the .NET 4.5 runtime](http://elegantcode.com/2012/08/23/net-4-5-operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-yikes/) which acts when installed as a drop-in replacement for the .NET 4 runtime and is used even if your code only targets .NET 4!**

From the linked article, the fix to the .Net 4.5/4.0 runtime has since been created by Microsoft as a hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748645

Comment: I tried with Intellitrace off, and the higher trust level settings.  This is currently a .NET 4.0 solution.  No change in the result.  Same issue.

Comment: Have you downloaded .Net 4.5? It doesn't matter if you've targetd .Net 4.0 in the project settings, I believe it will still run on the .Net 4.5 runtime and attempt to be backwards compatible.